# AngularJS, two APPS, single page, $location.search() change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On a single page I've got two AngularJS apps (not controllers). Both of them watch for the `$locationChangeSuccess` event by using `$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', ...)`.

If I manually change the hash in the URL in the browser, event handlers for `$locationChangeSuccess` fire in both apps.

However, if one of the apps changes the hash by calling `$location.search(...)` only the `$locationChangeSuccess` event handler defined in that apps gets called. The event handler in the other app does not fire.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8yw29em/2/) that shows the behaviour.

How do I get the other event handler to fire as well in this situation?